# Symfony2: How to remove an element from a Doctrine ArrayCollection (many-to-many relation)?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

I use the following code for my many-to-many relation in symfony2 (doctrine)

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity\Container", inversedBy="videosToSync")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="syncSchema")
 */
private $syncSchema;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->syncSchema = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); 
}

public function addSyncSchema(\BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity\Container $syncSchema)
{
    $this->syncSchema[] = $syncSchema;
}
```

Controller:

```
$entity->addSyncSchema($container);
$em->flush();
```

Now, how can I use this to remove a relation? Do I need to add a method to my entity like removeSyncSchema()? What would that look like?

Comment: Are you not doing doctrine:generate entities ?

Comment: oh... usually dont, but tried it and sure enough... thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're looking for the [`ArrayCollection::removeElement`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L118) method here.

```
public function removeSchema(SchemaInterface $schema)
{
    $this->schemata->removeElement($schema)

    return $this;
}
```

**tip:**

You can use [`ArrayCollection::add`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L254) to add elements to an existing collection. OOP.

In some cases you may also want to check wether already contains the element before adding it.

```
public function addSchema(SchemaInterface $schema)
{
    if (!$this->schemata->contains($schema)) {
        $this->schemata->add($schema);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: nice answer. +1 for checking before adding